# how to open shared folder file in local system file explorer using <a href=" "> </a>

Tags: html

```
 <a href="file://90.0.0.12/mydata/pdfFolder/data.pdf">shared file</a>
```

above link work in IE but not in Chrome and firefox.

how to open above link in my local system file explorer window using above code in chrome and firebox browser

Comment: Hi @Dharmendra Jadav if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Linking to local resources is disabled in all modern browsers due to security restrictions.
you can create a bat file (file.bat) with this commands be aware about the security issues.

```
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
start chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files %CD%\YOUR_HTML_FILE.html
```